# Jquery function is being called on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery which I want to run on load time but It doesn't seem to hit the load event. Here is my jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.field-of-work').load(function () {
        var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.field-of-work-wrapper');

        $wrapper.find('.position').hide();
        $wrapper.find('.position').find('select').val('');

    });
});
```

Why would the load event not get hit?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: Do you have jquery library reference in the head tag?

Comment: Yep as I have some other jquery that runs fine

Comment: Use this function in document.roady. put it first.

Comment: when is this code loaded? check that your are actually loading the jquery library (use fiddler to see that it actually loads and not returning 404 or something else). make sure you run your script after you load the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ready()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.field-of-work select').load(function () {
        var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.field-of-work-wrapper');

        $wrapper.find('.position').hide();
        $wrapper.find('.position').find('select').val('');

    });
});
```

Comment: Yep that worked :), but in the jquery spec it did state I could use the other way to do the document ready... nevermind

Answer (score 0):

`$(function()` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){})` and your load event is fired before the document ready event.

If you want your code inside the load listener to fire on page loading, you should put it outside of any `$(function()` or `$(document).ready()` like this :

```
$('.field-of-work').on('load', function () {
    var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.field-of-work-wrapper');

    $wrapper.find('.position').hide();
    $wrapper.find('.position').find('select').val('');

});

$(function(){
   /* Your other code here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.field-of-work').load(function () {
        var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.field-of-work-wrapper');

        $wrapper.find('.position').hide();
        $wrapper.find('.position').find('select').val('');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Load function correctly?

Load requires an "url" as a parameter and returns the HTML into the matched element.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

**`Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.`**

```
load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )Returns: jQuery
```

Do you want to perform the actions inside your load method right after the page has been loaded?

You may want to use "ready()" instead of it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.field-of-work-wrapper');

        $wrapper.find('.position').hide();
        $wrapper.find('.position').find('select').val('');
});
```

Or did you just want to add an Event Handler load to it (like

```
.on( "load", handler ).
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/